# Split text with regex in nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to find sql script in a file to split in nodejs. Before split to text I add like `-split-` seperator with regex replace to begining of the sql script as the below:

SQL file:

```
/* this is a comment for create table */
--this is another comment for create table

create table test1 (comment varchar);
create temporary table test2 (comment varchar);

insert into text1 values('this is a comment for create table ')
```

Regex replace operation:

```
sqlText
.replace(/\s+create(\s+|global\s+|temporary\s+)table\s+/gi, `-split- CREATE $1 TABLE `)
```

Expected output:

```
/* this is a comment for create table */
--this is another comment for create table

-split- CREATE TABLE test1 (comment varchar);
-split- CREATE temporary TABLE test2 (comment varchar);

insert into text1 values('this is a comment for create table ')
```

But i get:

```
/* this is a comment for -split- CREATE TABLE */
--this is another comment for -split- CREATE TABLE

-split- CREATE TABLE test1 (comment varchar);
-split- CREATE temporary TABLE test2 (comment varchar);

insert into text1 values('this is a comment for -split- CREATE TABLE ')
```

How can I exclude the query sentences in the comment line and quotes?

Answer (score 0):

1. First `split` the text into lines `.split(/\n/)`
2. Loop with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each line check if it line begins with `create table`, if so change it as you want `-split- CREATE TABLE`

```js
let sqlText = `/* this is a comment for create table */
--this is another comment for create table

create table test1 (comment varchar);
create table test2 (comment varchar);

insert into text1 values('this is a comment for create table ')
`;
console.log(sqlText.split(/\n/).map(line=>line.replace(/^create\s+table\s+/gi, `-split- CREATE TABLE `)).join('\n'))
```

**`Notice:`** the `^` means "starts with".

### UPDATE

more simple with RegExp flag [`m`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline)

```js
console.log(sqlText.replace(/^create\s+table\s+/gmi, `-split- CREATE TABLE `))
                                                ☝️
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
const str = `/* this is a comment for create table */
--this is another comment for create table

create table test1 (comment varchar);
create table test2 (comment varchar);

insert into text1 values('this is a comment for create table ')`
console.log(str.replace(/(\/\*[^]*?\*\/|^\s*--.*|'[^\\']*(?:\\[^][^\\']*)*'|"[^\\"]*(?:\\[^][^\\"]*)*")|[^\S\n\r]*create\s+table\s+/gmi, (_, x) => x || `-split- CREATE TABLE `))
```

We skip multiline comments (`\/\*[^]*?\*\/`), single line comments (`^\s*--.*`), single quote literals (`'[^\\']*(?:\\[^][^\\']*)*'`) and double quote literals.

The `[^\S\n\r]*create\s+table\s+` regex part finds matches outside of afore-mentioned patterns.

Comment: Thanks it works. How can I use $1-$9 parameters if there is a specific word between `create` and `table`. Like `create global table` or `create temporary table`. Replace syntax is `create(\s+|global\s+|temporary\s+)table`

Comment: @Emrah Note that `create(\s+|global\s+|temporary\s+)table` is not replace syntax, it is a regex that can only be used to search for a pattern, not replace with this.

Comment: @Emrah I am sorry, I do not understand this new requirement. `$1` through `$9` are backreferences, not parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the solution with v1-n parameters is: `.replace(/(\/\*[^]*?\*\/|--.+|'[^\\']*(?:\\[^][^\\']*)*'|"[^\\"]*(?:\\[^][^\\"]*)*")|[^\S\n\r]*\s+create(|\s+or\s+replace)\s+type\s+/gmi, (_, x, v1) => x || '-split- CREATE ${v1} TYPE ')`